# Application should keep running even after Kafka connection is broken

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I am publishing messages to external team which consumes messages for Kafka and returns us a response. Whenever our application is running and it tries to send publish message to Kafka and if Kafka connection is lost or down then our application throws exception.
I want my application should not break even if Kafka connection is broken.
The Kafka topics are handled by other team and I cannot change their code.
Is there any way, I can keep my application running by bypassing the Kafka step and continue with other processing without having any impact?

Answer (score 0):

You can increase producer config `retries` and set it to a large number, eg, `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: I have increased the number of tries. Yet it is not working

Comment: What does "not working" mean exactly? What error/exception do you get?

Comment: The Kafka gets connected and later a logger is shown - hard shutdown. Also the healthcheck for the API fails

Comment: Can you share the error message? Just update your question.